# How can I mask a Nginx virtual host redirect?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I was asked to make a rewrite rule to redirect a virtual host subdomain to another virtual host managed by the same Nginx server. That works fine but I'd like to mask the URL redirect in the browser.

There is a configuration file for each virtual host: subdomain.mydomain.com.conf configuration file was made from original www.mydomain.com.conf with required substitutions.

This is www.mydomain.com.conf virtual host configuration file:

```
server {
   listen    127.0.0.1:80;
   listen    443 ssl;
   server_name  www.mydomain.com;

   access_log  /var/log/nginx/www.mydomain.com-access_log main;
   error_log   /var/log/nginx/www.mydomain.com-error_log;

   root /var/www/html/www.mydomain.com;

   index index.php index.html index.htm;
...
   location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }
...
```

I made a Nginx rewrite rule to redirect URLs beginning with www.mydomain.com/subdomain to  subdomain.mydomain.com:

```
   location /subdomain {   
        rewrite ^/$ subdomain.mydomain.com$request_uri last;
   }
```

I found a link that explains how to make an internal redirect :

http://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/436/nginx-rewrite-url-examples-with-without-redirect-address#.VFKqiYXXqPK

I made several attempts but the redirect is always shown.

As I'm new to Nginx, can somebody help me out ?

best regards,

Comment: Internal redirects cannot change server block. You need http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

Comment: JFYI, you rewrite rule inside location makes no sense.

Comment: It doens't make sense. That's content duplication.